# Node Js taking to much time to console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Hello This is my first question in stackoverflow please forgive me if I ask something wrong. I'm made button if I click it it will delete quantity by one. So after showing that on UI. I'm sending the data to server. But when I console log the req.body it taking 20-30s to show it. Sometimes it looks likes nothing happend.
here is the code

```
  const handleDeliver = () => {
const newQuantity = parseInt(item?.quantity) - 1;
const newSold = parseInt(item?.sold) + 1;
if (newQuantity >= 0) {
  const updateInfo = {
    quantity: newQuantity + "",
    sold: newSold + "",
  };
  setItem({
    ...item,
    ...updateInfo,
  });
} else {
  toast.warning("Please Restock the Car.");
}
```

};

```
  useEffect(() => {
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/items/${id}`, {
  method: "PUT", // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    quantity: item?.quantity,
    sold: item?.sold,
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    toast("Success:", data);
  });
```

}, [item])

```
return(
      <MDBBtn
          className="w-100 my-5"
          color="danger"
          onClick={() => {
            handleDeliver();
          }}
        >
          Delivered
        </MDBBtn>
```

This is the code on client side:

```
    app.put('/items/:id', async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.status(500).send('testing');
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the following code:

```
setItem({
...item,
...updateInfo});
```

to

```
setItem(updateInfo);
```